# How to say "i just want to do X right now"

Tags: grammar

"i just want to do X" Or something like "all i want to do is do X"

Example:

1. "All I want to do is lie down and rest"
2. "I just want to play that game forever"

If I tried to translate that it would be something like

1. **とりあえず**何よりも寝転びたい
2. （やっぱ）あのゲームを永遠にやりたい**だけ**だ

I understand also that this can have different nuances, so for example there is one nuance that's like "this is all that I want to do in this moment" because everything else around you is unsatisfying, and the other nuance being something like "i have no other motivation but this / its not that I want to do Y, I just want to do X"

How would you translate both of those nuances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, my translation is:

> 1. 何よりも今は寝転がって休みたい。
> 2. あのゲームを永遠にやれればそれでいい。

---

For the example 1, your word choice of 何よりも is very good.

And とりあえず is also fine. But you should note that it has the nuance of postponing everything else to handle current problem (that you are really exhausted now), so it may imply "after I get up, I'll do the next task." When you don't want to consider the future at all, avoid using とりあえず.

Using とにかく instead of 何よりも (or even using both) is also a good choice.

---

For the example 2, not so bad, but if you say 「〜たいだけだ」, it might sound like you are making an excuse. Instead, I used 「〜ばそれでいい」, that literally means "if 〜, it's enough." It has a nuance of not being concerned about anything else.

やっぱ is not suitable here. Its nuance can be either:

1. withdrawing what you said/thought before.
2. reconfirming what you said/thought before.

Both seem to differ from what you want.